# Count how many different kinds of elements in python list

Tags: python

What is the pythonic way to check how many different kinds of elements in python list. something like:

```
lst = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
s = set()        
for l in lst:
    s.add(l) 
result = list(s)
```

Comment: Almost. Instead of adding each item individually just use `set(lst)`. And to find out how many items there are, use `len()`.

Comment: actually I want to know what is the value.  I just want to know if I could make it in one or two lines